# Review audits for migrated questions

Tags: discussion, bug, review-audits, migration

I just failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5305575) because while it was pretty obviously very poor quality, there was a great big notification on it saying that it had been migrated to meta which would certainly be the place for it if it could be cleaned up a lot. As such, I figured nothing else needed to be done here especially if 5 other people had already reviewed the post and voted for a migration.

Should I really have been expected to down vote it as well?

Comment: Wait... it told you that it was migrated before you passed/failed the audit? That's probably a bug.

Comment: Yes, the great big "migrated to [insert SE site here]" box was shown on it.

Comment: @hichris123 I don't think there are conditions in the review audit code for migrated questions because they didn't anticipate them getting used (or just plain didn't think about them). [Remember this?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231964/audits-mess-up-on-migrated-questions)

Comment: @animuson That's probably true. At least you can do something with this audit.

Comment: I think you should add the 'bug' tag to your question.